# Azure Postgres "flexible server" could not write to file pg_tblspc: "No space left on device"

Tags: postgresql, azure

I just created a new instance of PostgreSQL Flexible Server, version 14, on Azure (Memory Optimized, E8ds_v4, 8 vCores, 64 GiB RAM, 512 GiB storage). I took a backup of a "single" server, version 11, and restored it to the new instance. The new instance has 512 GB of storage. The database dump is only 13 GB. When I try to do a basic query against the big tables (500M rows), I get the following error:

`Query 1 ERROR: ERROR:  could not write to file "pg_tblspc/16386/PG_14_202107181/pgsql_tmp/pgsql_tmp28927.79": No space left on device`

I've been searching for an hour, but I can't find ANY documentation about how an error about *disk* space could be resolved on an instance of Postgres on Azure. Can anyone tell me if there are server parameters I could tweak that would increase the size of the space or cache for running queries in memory that would avoid this problem?

Additionally, I tried to open an actual ticket with Microsoft support, and I can't find any way to do that. I'm paying many, many thousands of dollars a month for just the few dozen services I have, and it seems there's no way to contact support?! Am I missing something here?

Well, for reference, the query is:

```
SELECT c.code, c.parameter_count, COUNT(t.*) FROM calibrations c
JOIN variables v ON v.calibration_id = c.id
JOIN tunings t ON t.id = v.tuning_id
GROUP BY code, parameter_count
```

This finishes on the old instance, though it takes hours.

UPDATE: I just increased the allocation of the new instance to the "Memory Optimized, E16ds_v4, 16 vCores, 128 GiB RAM, 512 GiB storage" version, and the query completed in 10 minutes. I guess you get what you pay for.

Comment: `When I try to do a basic query against the big tables` - the text of your query and the structure of your tables would be helpful in determining the source of the problem.

Comment: pg_dump (in my experience) can be 1/5 to 1/10 the size of the actual restored data depending on indexes and compression used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Azure Postgres Flexible Server use `/mnt/pg_tmp` location for temporary tables spaces. I'm not sure about the available space for `/mnt`, it could depend on the overall disk storage or even could be fixed. Didn't find how to know it.

For me it was 4TB database (dump 333GB) and I used 8TB disk storage. I got the same error every time when I tried to restore my database. It failed on index creation (total count: ~200, size: 3GB-140GB, 4-16 jobs)

Then I found `azure.enable_temp_tablespaces_on_local_ssd` in server parameters. If you set it to `OFF` the disk storage (8TB in my case) will be used for temporary tables spaces. Once I did it, I have never seen this error again.

Hope this helps

Comment: The flag seems backwards, but this sounds like a reasonable thing to play with if this should happen again. My database is a paltry 3.4 GB (dumped), so I would have a lot of room to use for temp space.

Comment: I see these Azure instance types have ephemeral "local SSD" storage. It looks like Microsoft has configured this ephemeral drive for temporary tables and this setting controls whether the ephemeral local SSD or the persistent, network-attached storage is used. You can see ephemeral disk per instance type in this table https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/edv4-edsv4-series#edsv4-series

Answer (score 0):

Your query writes a lot of temporary files. After more than 70GB worth of temp files, your temporary tablespace is full, and you get an error.

The "basic query" seems to be more complicated than you think, or you forgot a join condition somewhere.